# Trying to create buttons with WebPy, getting a type error

Tags: python, html, web.py

When using The webpy library for python. Im currently trying to make a buttons. Here is my HTML File, Python File and Error.

Code.py - Problem Area

```
onOff = form.Form(
    form.Button('On'),
    form.Button('Off'),
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
            f = onoff()
            return render.formtest(f)

    def POST(self):
            form = onOff()
            if not form.validates():
                    return render.formtest(form)
            else:
                    return "Great Success!"
```

formtest.html - Entire Page

```
$def with (f)

<form name="main" method="post">
$if not form.valid: <p class="error">Try again, American:</p>
$:form.render()
<input type="submit" /> </form>
```

Error Message-Main Error

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /
GET() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Python  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py in                          
handle_class, line 437
Web GET http://192.168.0.34:8080/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GET` method is supposed to accept two parameters, `self` (the current object) and a url, change it to this

```
def GET(self, url):
    f = onoff()
    return render.formtest(f)
```

Comment: Im now getting the error: <type 'exceptions.NameError'> at /
global name 'form' is not defined

Python templates/formtest.html in __template__, line 3
Web GET http://192.168.0.34:8080

Comment: at this point i'll advice you to read the documentation of `web.py`, you haven't understood the basics yet http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#getpost

Comment: Never mind, got it fixed. i called the wrong variable in the template.